# Adding up a sum of 2 numbers into A Masked Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add the sum of two numbers such as 350 + 400 to a Masked Textbox using a button. I am sorry I am pretty new to C#. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   maskedTextBox2.Text.Sum = 350 + 400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   maskedTextBox2.Text = (350 + 400).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set the `MaskedTextBox.Text` property. Note that the result of `350 + 400` will be of type `System.Int32`; however, `MaskedTextBox.Text` is a `System.String`. C# will not perform the type conversion implicitly (you'll get a compile-time error), so you need to convert the result of this addition to a string. Here's an example:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox2.Text = (350 + 400).ToString();
}
```

For more information on types, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
masketTexBox2.Text = (350+400).ToString();
```

This can help. Appending value to textbox control is done throught .Text property.
And at the end, I just converted sum into string

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   maskedTextBox2.Text = (350 + 400).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really just want the sum to show up in the textbox, right? So really, you just need to work with the `Text` property of the box.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   maskedTextBox2.Text = 350 + 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the .Text property of maskedTextBox2 is a string, it will not have a .Sum property.

Try this:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox2.Text = (350 + 400).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox2.Text = (350 + 400).ToString();
}
```

Unless there is some format of the MaskedTextBox that is preventing the assignment, that should be fine.